# Inserting large amounts data into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a VSTO Excel Add-In which is used to retrieve data from another application and insert it into an Excel worksheet. Due to the potential for lots of pieces of data to be inserted into a spreadsheet, performance is a concern. Potentially thousands of rows could be inserted.

Here is the method which inserts data into an Excel spreadsheet.

Note: Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

```
private Worksheet Worksheet { get { return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet; } }
private Range Cells { get { return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells; } }

private void PopulateCurrentWorksheet(ReportData data, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("No valid ReportData available");

    // NOTE: Excel uses indexing that starts at 1
    if (columnIndex == 0)
        columnIndex = 1;

    if (rowIndex == 0)
        rowIndex = 1;

    int startingRowIndex = rowIndex;

    foreach (ReportColumn column in data.Columns)
    {
        Cells[columnIndex][rowIndex].Value = column.ColumnName;
        Cells[columnIndex][rowIndex].Font.Bold = true; // put the header in bold
        for (int i = 0; i < column.ColumnData.Length; i++)
        {
            rowIndex++; // move down a cell to the next row
            Cells[columnIndex][rowIndex] = column.ColumnData.ElementAt(i);
        }
        rowIndex = startingRowIndex;
        columnIndex++; // move right a cell to the next column
    }

    Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
}
```

Below is the `ReportData` class (and associated `ReportColumn` class) which holds data retrieved from an external application to be inserted into a worksheet

```
public class ReportData
{
    public ReportData(IEnumerable<ReportColumn> columns)
    {
        Columns = columns ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("No valid columns available");
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReportColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class ReportColumn
{
    public ReportColumn(string columnName, object[] columnData)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        ColumnData = columnData;
    }

    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public object[] ColumnData { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to insert data into a worksheet which results in over 100k rows, there is a significant performance hit. Is there anyway I could improve the code to make it faster? Any other advice is welcomed too.

Comment: Try assigning Range.Value of the top-left target cell on the target sheet, to a 2D array that contains your values. That's 1 worksheet write operation instead of 100K x NumberOfColumns. Basically `ReportData` wants a `ToArray()` method.

Comment: Also, how exactly are `Cells` and `Worksheet` defined? Seeing the rest of the code would be beneficial, too: why is the method working off whatever sheet happens to be active rather than from a specific worksheet?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Have included how Cells and Worksheets are defined. The method is working off the active sheet because there is no use case for the Add-In where we would want a non-active worksheet to be written to.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have just tried your suggestion of only doing one worksheet write operation, and it is drastically improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public class ReportData
> {
>     public ReportData(IEnumerable<ReportColumn> columns)
>     {
>         Columns = columns ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("No valid columns available");
>     }
>
>     public IEnumerable<ReportColumn> Columns { get; set; }
> }
> ```

The `Columns` property should be `get`-only.

> ```
> public string ColumnName { get; set; } 
> public object[] ColumnData { get; set; }
> ```

Same with these two: it makes no sense to set them in the constructor, even throw an exception if it's `null`, if you can legally construct the object and then merrily do this:

```
var data = new ReportData(Enumerable.Empty<ReportColumn>()) { Columns = null };
```

Note that `IEnumerable<T>` things should indeed never be `null`, but any `IEnumerable<T>` can still be empty without being `null`. As such, the guard clause is insufficient, since it appears to be there to protect against creating a `new ReportData` that wouldn't have any columns - `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is a perfectly valid input that should be guarded against.

```
public class ReportData
{
    public reportData(IEnumerable<ReportColumn> columns)
    {
        var reportColumns = columns ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(...);
        if (!reportColumns.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(...);
        }

        Columns = reportColumns;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ReportColumns> Columns { get; }
}
```

Now there's no way a `ReportData` object can have 0 columns, be it during or after construction.

These two could be expression-bodied auto-properties:

> ```
> private Worksheet Worksheet { get { return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet; } }
> private Range Cells { get { return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells; } }
> ```

Like this:

```
private Worksheet Worksheet => Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
private Range Cells => Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells;
```

This is a serious problem:

> ```
> // NOTE: Excel uses indexing that starts at 1
> if (columnIndex == 0)
>     columnIndex = 1;
>
> if (rowIndex == 0)
>     rowIndex = 1;
> ```

Consider consistently using `{ }` braces to avoid such implicit scopes.

If the `columnIndex` or `rowIndex` supplied was `0`, then the calling code is off-by-one and this silent one-upping is literally *hiding* that bug, and there's a very very very high chance that the next call is going to pass a `1` that you're not going to offset, which will produce *a* result, but very unlikely the *expected* result.

Consider:

- Throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` given `0` for column or row index.
- Adding XML docs to document that the index parameters are 1-based - OR document them as 0-based, and abstract away the fact that Excel's object model is 1-based by offsetting every provided value, not just `0`. In any case, you need XML docs to say this.

---

My experience with VSTO is that if you don't properly release ***all*** the COM objects you ever access, then when your program exits you'll be left with a ghost EXCEL.EXE process in Task Manager, because .NET will be holding on to RCW objects wrapping COM/unmanaged objects that won't be garbage-collected like managed objects would be.

Hence, avoid double-dots like this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
```

That's essentially leaking `ThisAddIn`, `Application`, and `ActiveSheet` objects.

Every single access to `Cells` is re-dereferencing the same `ActiveSheet` over and over and over, every time. That makes a lot of redundant member access.

```
var addin = Globals.ThisAddIn;
var application = addin.Application;
var activeSheet = application.ActiveSheet;

var allCells = activeSheet.Cells;
var cell = allCells[columnIndex][rowIndex];
cell.Value = column.ColumnName;

var cellFont = cell.Font;
cellFont.Bold = true;
```

...and then each of these objects need to be released... in the reverse order they were accessed:

```
Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(cellFont);
Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(cell);
Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(allCells);
...
```

Miss one single COM object, and the EXCEL.EXE process won't be able to shut down correctly.

That makes it a pretty good reason to avoid writing to individual cells, ...regardless of the performance hit ;-)